# What are folder extension? How do I create my own extension?

Tags: windows-7

I have heard about file extension but never heard about folder extension.

I mean to say if I create a folder called `test` and then rename it to `.test{ED7BA470-8E54-465E-825C-99712043E01C}` it opens control panel instead of opening the folder.

So my question is how do I create my own extension? I tried searching a lot, but couldn't find anything valuable.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See that :)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997573.aspx

If you can program, you can try that:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/namespcextguide1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Example:

Make a text document. Rename it to New Text Document.note

Right-click the file, then press Properties.
After "Pick an app", press Change...
Select the app you want to open a file with the file extension with.
Press Apply, then OK.
Open the file. It should now open with the app you chosen.
You should also see the icon change.

Also, about folder extensions:
Folder are marked with .dir like normal files. You can see it in Properties --> General. Folders are technically just a zip file. So if you put .something, you're changing the folder extension.
The .something tells Explorer that it is connected to an Explorer popup.
You can see a ton of those in a location in Regedit.
But if you put .zip .txt or other extensions, it won't work.